# Why does a computer need a name server to operate on a modern network?

Tags: networking

I completed a quiz that contained a question about the **4 things every computer must have configured to work on a modern network**.

I read everything and saw only the assertion that name servers were required... yet everything that I also just learned certainly does not require a name server right? I've got my nonroutable space... and I can NAT out of there and to server on the internet without any name servers right??

Do you think that "Modern" was just a tricky word here and the question surely ought to mean  that no MODERN network would be useful without the 4 things configured?

Answer (score 1):

Nameservers translate a name (think domain name) to some form of record, and ultimately to an A (or AAAA) record which is an IP address.

So if you never want to use domain names, then no, you don't really need a nameserver in theory (in practice this situation would be VERY rare). If at any point you want to translate a domain to an IP, you will need nameservers. This all happens at a different layer to IP routing etc.

Beyond just simple Domain -> IP Translation there's other records like SRV, MX etc that play a part in regular every day internet use. (Generally these will ultimately still involve a domain to IP translation in the end also)